# My NGINX reverse proxy does not re-route traffic to an external VM

Tags: api, ssl, nginx, tls1.2, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am having two VM, on hosts Nginx and the other is also a standalone server. 
I will call the VMs as follows;

- a standalone = `Cash`  *serving https*
- the one hosting the Nginx= `LOCAL` *serving http*

In order for `LOCAL` to communicate with `CASH`, we use a `NGINX` **reverse proxy proxy** to **redirect** `HTTP` traffic to `HTTPS` and handle the `TLS` handshakes and in case the `CASH` makes a call to `LOCAL` the `NGINX` again accepts this `HTTPS` traffic and redirecting it to `LOCAL`'s `HTTP` as shown;

```
upstream  api_http_within_this_vm {
    server 127.0.0.1:9001;  #LOCAL VM caal it HOST VM application
}
#  SENDING HTTP TRAFFIC TO OUR HTTPS ENDPOINT Call CASH
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name         10.0.0.13;

  location / {
    proxy_pass  https://  api_https_to_another_vm;

    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/sites-available/signed_by_CASH.pem;
    proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/sites-available/local_key_used_to_generate_csr_for_CASH_to_sign.key;
    proxy_ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2;
    proxy_ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/sites-available/CASH_CA.crt;

    proxy_ssl_verify       on;
    proxy_ssl_verify_depth 2;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
  }

}

upstream   api_https_to_another_vm {
  server 10.0.0.13:8080; # CASH's VM IP and PORT
}


#  RECIEVING HTTPS TRAFFIC ENDPOINT from CASH TO OUR LOCAL HTTP ENDPOINT 
server {
  listen 5555 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:5555 ssl http2;
  server_name         1270.0.0.1;

  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://api_http_within_this_vm;

    proxy_set_header X_CUSTOM_HEADER $http_x_custom_header;
    proxy_buffering    off;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
  }


  ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/sites-available/signed_by_CASH.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/sites-available/local_key_used_to_generate_csr_for_CASH_to_sign.key;
  ssl_verify_client      off;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
}
```

**MY SUCCESS**

- The traffic from `CASH` to `LOCAL` work well.

**MY CHALLENGE**

- The traffic from `LOCAL` to `CASH` does NOT work. I get 502 Bad Request yet when I use `curl https://10.0.0.13:8080/` directly without **Reverse proxy**`LOCAL` to `CASH` I see some output even if no handshake happens.

Anywhere am going wrong, please advise.....

Secondly, does Nginx only redirect traffic to IPs within the VM or even to other VMs?

I majorly want to achieve this kind of [leg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0sqgxl0oyw4) that has failed on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this configuration over time, I had to trace with a `tcpdump` and even checked my logs because I suspected the problem is network driven. I found out the actually the client `CASH` was dropping the connection before the TLS handshake completes.

```
2019/03/02 06:54:58 [error] 27569#27569: *62 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: 1270.0.0.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://xx.xx.xx.xx:1000/", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx:80"
```

Thanks to all that viewed, but the script is correct.